# Wifi issue. QCA6164 drops connection after ~2 mins. Missing firmware?

Tags: wireless, 16.04, atheros, firmware

I'm having some issues with my wifi connectivity. I think the most interesting line from the excerpt below is:

```
Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2.
```

But I just cant figure out how to fix it. I have downloaded both old and new firmware and `sudo apt-get update/upgrade/upgrade-dist`.

My `/etc/modprobe.d` file looks like this: `options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y`.

I have seen many other with the same or similar issue, but any attempt at following the solution in those thread has either not worked or made matters worse. Any help is much appreciated. As long as I run:
`sudo systemctl restart network-manager` I can access wifi again, but it will last for about 2 minutes.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep ath10k 

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3828]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0041] (rev 20)
Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3545]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
[    2.918712] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.198278] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.570758] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.720287] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[  545.216430] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
```

-

```
$ dmesg | grep ath
[    2.601530] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8
irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.887505] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.177481] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca6164 hw2.1 (0x05010000, 0x003405ff sub 17aa:3545) fw SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[    4.177491] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.246892] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    4.246896] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.246898] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.246899] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    4.263690] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    6.444473] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   18.080843] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[   22.760185] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8242
[   22.760188] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   22.760190] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   22.760191] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   22.760192] ath: Country alpha2 being used: NO
[   22.760193] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   22.760195] ath: regdomain 0x8242 dynamically updated by country IE
```

-

```
$ iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'
enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                ESSID:"bever"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                ESSID:"bever_5G"
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
```

Comment: By chance, is your router set to autoselect the channel? Could you please try a fixed channel; 1, 6 or 11? http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/spa8000-8-port-ip-telephony-gateway/108636-4625-001.png

Comment: My router is on channel 6. The problem also occurs on other routers. Ethernet cable works fine. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It may be missing some firmware but obviously finds usable firmware; otherwise, it would not work at all. Whether it is the optimum firmware is a question. Let's try upgrading the firmware. From the terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and test. Please show us:

```
dmesg | grep ath
```